# Profile page not showing up after successful login via FB/Google

Tags: java, android

I am working on android project, in that i use Social Login FB and Google.So when I click on fb/google so account gets created for new user and for existing user its get logged in. All data gets stored and retrieved from database But the problem is that after login its nit showing profile page of user
Login.java file code :

```
    public class Login_A extends Activity {


    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;


    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    View top_view;

    TextView login_title_txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 26) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_USER);
        }

        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        this.getWindow()
                .setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser=mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        // if the user is already login through facebook then we will logout the user automatically
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(Variables.pref_name,MODE_PRIVATE);

        findViewById(R.id.facebook_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Loginwith_FB();
            }
        });



        findViewById(R.id.google_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Sign_in_with_gmail();
            }
        });



        findViewById(R.id.Goback).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        top_view=findViewById(R.id.top_view);



        login_title_txt=findViewById(R.id.login_title_txt);
        login_title_txt.setText("You need a "+getString(R.string.app_name)+"\naccount to Continue");



        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("By signing up, you confirm that you agree to our \n Terms of Use and have read and understood \n our Privacy Policy.");
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {
                Open_Privacy_policy();
            }
            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                super.updateDrawState(ds);
                ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            }
        };
        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 99, ss.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_terms_condition_txt);
        textView.setText(ss);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());


        printKeyHash();


    }


    public void Open_Privacy_policy(){
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(Variables.privacy_policy));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onEnterAnimationComplete() {
        super.onEnterAnimationComplete();
        AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        anim.setDuration(200);
        top_view.startAnimation(anim);
        top_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        top_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_from_top, R.anim.out_from_bottom);

    }


    // Bottom two function are related to Fb implementation
    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    //facebook implementation
    public void Loginwith_FB(){

        LoginManager.getInstance()
                .logInWithReadPermissions(Login_A.this,
                        Arrays.asList("public_profile","email"));

        // initialze the facebook sdk and request to facebook for login
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()  {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                Log.d("resp_token",loginResult.getAccessToken()+"");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
                Toast.makeText(Login_A.this, "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d("resp",""+error.toString());
                Toast.makeText(Login_A.this, "Login Error"+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });


    }

    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(final AccessToken token) {
        // if user is login then this method will call and
        // facebook will return us a token which will user for get the info of user
        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        Log.d("resp_token",token.getToken()+"");
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Functions.Show_loader(Login_A.this,false,false);
                            final String id = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId();
                            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(token, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                                    Functions.cancel_loader();
                                    Log.d("resp",user.toString());
                                    //after get the info of user we will pass to function which will store the info in our server

                                    String fname=""+user.optString("first_name");
                                    String lname=""+user.optString("last_name");


                                    if(fname.equals("") || fname.equals("null"))
                                        fname=getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

                                    if(lname.equals("") || lname.equals("null"))
                                        lname="";

                                    Call_Api_For_Signup(""+id,fname
                                            ,lname,
                                            "https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?width=500&width=500",
                                            "facebook");

                                }
                            });

                            // here is the request to facebook sdk for which type of info we have required
                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            parameters.putString("fields", "last_name,first_name,email");
                            request.setParameters(parameters);
                            request.executeAsync();
                        } else {
                            Functions.cancel_loader();
                            Toast.makeText(Login_A.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
        if(requestCode==123){
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
        else if(mCallbackManager!=null)
            mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }



    //google Implementation
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    public void Sign_in_with_gmail(){
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(Login_A.this);
        if (account != null) {
            String id=account.getId();
            String fname=""+account.getGivenName();
            String lname=""+account.getFamilyName();

            String pic_url;
            if(account.getPhotoUrl()!=null) {
                pic_url = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            }else {
                pic_url="null";
            }



            if(fname.equals("") || fname.equals("null"))
                fname=getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

            if(lname.equals("") || lname.equals("null"))
                lname="User";
            Call_Api_For_Signup(id,fname,lname,pic_url,"gmail");


        }
        else {
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 123);
        }

    }


    //Relate to google login
    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            if (account != null) {
                String id=account.getId();
                String fname=""+account.getGivenName();
                String lname=""+account.getFamilyName();

                // if we do not get the picture of user then we will use default profile picture

                String pic_url;
                if(account.getPhotoUrl()!=null) {
                    pic_url = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
                }else {
                    pic_url="null";
                }


                if(fname.equals("") || fname.equals("null"))
                    fname=getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

                if(lname.equals("") || lname.equals("null"))
                    lname="User";

                Call_Api_For_Signup(id,fname,lname,pic_url,"gmail");


            }
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Log.w("Error message", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        }

    }




    // this function call an Api for Signin
    private void Call_Api_For_Signup(String id,
                                     String f_name,
                                     String l_name,
                                     String picture,
                                     String singnup_type) {


        PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
        try {
            packageInfo =getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String appversion=packageInfo.versionName;

        JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();
        try {

            parameters.put("fb_id", id);
            parameters.put("first_name",""+f_name);
            parameters.put("last_name", ""+l_name);
            parameters.put("profile_pic",picture);
            parameters.put("gender","m");
            parameters.put("version",appversion);
            parameters.put("signup_type",singnup_type);
            parameters.put("device",Variables.device);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Functions.Show_loader(this,false,false);
        ApiRequest.Call_Api(this, Variables.SignUp, parameters, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void Responce(String resp) {
                Functions.cancel_loader();
                Parse_signup_data(resp);

            }
        });

    }




    // if the signup successfull then this method will call and it store the user info in local
    public void Parse_signup_data(String loginData){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(loginData);
            String code=jsonObject.optString("code");
            if(code.equals("200")){
                JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("msg");
                JSONObject userdata = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(Variables.u_id,userdata.optString("fb_id"));
                editor.putString(Variables.f_name,userdata.optString("first_name"));
                editor.putString(Variables.l_name,userdata.optString("last_name"));
                editor.putString(Variables.u_name,userdata.optString("username"));
                editor.putString(Variables.gender,userdata.optString("gender"));
                editor.putString(Variables.u_pic,userdata.optString("profile_pic"));
                editor.putString(Variables.api_token,userdata.optString("tokon"));
                editor.putBoolean(Variables.islogin,true);
                editor.commit();
                Variables.sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(Variables.pref_name,MODE_PRIVATE);
                Variables.user_id=Variables.sharedPreferences.getString(Variables.u_id,"");

                Variables.Reload_my_videos=true;
                Variables.Reload_my_notification=true;
                top_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class));



            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, ""+jsonObject.optString("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    // this function will print the keyhash of your project
    // which is very helpfull during Fb login implementation
    public void printKeyHash()  {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName() , PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for(Signature signature:info.signatures)
            {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.i("keyhash" , Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the activity you are trying to launch is MainMenuActivity? i.e Profile Page that you are talking about?

Comment: Show an example of what UI you expect to be presented after a successful sign-in with Facebook? Facebook SDK will not show a user profile screen. It only shows UI related to sign in process and when finished returns back to your application. You have to create and start new activity or fragment with user profile interface

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `finish()` before launching activity in `Parse_signup_data()` change that

```
public void Parse_signup_data(String loginData){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(loginData);
        String code=jsonObject.optString("code");
        if(code.equals("200")){
            JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("msg");
            JSONObject userdata = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(Variables.u_id,userdata.optString("fb_id"));
            editor.putString(Variables.f_name,userdata.optString("first_name"));
            editor.putString(Variables.l_name,userdata.optString("last_name"));
            editor.putString(Variables.u_name,userdata.optString("username"));
            editor.putString(Variables.gender,userdata.optString("gender"));
            editor.putString(Variables.u_pic,userdata.optString("profile_pic"));
            editor.putString(Variables.api_token,userdata.optString("tokon"));
            editor.putBoolean(Variables.islogin,true);
            editor.commit();
            Variables.sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(Variables.pref_name,MODE_PRIVATE);
            Variables.user_id=Variables.sharedPreferences.getString(Variables.u_id,"");

            Variables.Reload_my_videos=true;
            Variables.Reload_my_notification=true;
            top_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class));
            finish(); // it should be called after starting Activity



        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+jsonObject.optString("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: 2020-07-04 19:49:38.118 20316-20316/com.jolley.TopIndia E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout  .........  this is the above error showing in logcat

Comment: I think now it's the problem of other activity ... where you are putting RecyclerView you need to check it in MainMenuActivity.class you can check this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/q/29141729/9365212

Comment: this is my activityMainMenu.xml file code : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:background="@color/white"/>`